# How to check if decorator is present on view from Middleware

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have a django application that requires that a session is set for quite a bit of functionality, I want to stop worrying about checking if it is set in the views so I am moving it to midddleware, however, I still have a few views that need the be excluded from the middleware.

I have decided to decorate the specific views that do not need the middleware, but I am unsure how to check if the decorator is present. Is this possible?

So far I have attempted to bind it to the request variable but that is not working.

```
class CheckPropertyMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    @staticmethod
    def process_view(request, view_func, args, kwargs):
        print(request.property_not_important)
        if not request.session.get('property'):
            print('property not selected')
            messages.error(request, 'You need to select a property to use the system.')
            # return redirect(reverse('home', args=[request.client_url]))
        else:
            print('property selected')

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.
        return response


def property_not_important(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.property_not_important = True
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that uses a decorator to disable the middleware for a specific view.

Here is the way that sets attributes on the view function and checks if it is present:

```
def property_not_important(function):
    """
    Decorator
    """
    orig_func = function
    setattr(orig_func, 'property_not_important', True)

    return function


class ExcludePropertyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    @staticmethod
    def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        prop_not_important = getattr(view_func, 'property_not_important', False)
        if prop_not_important:
            print('property not important')
            return view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
        return None

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Here is a solution checking the name of the method:

```
class ExcludePropertyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    @staticmethod
    def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if view_func.__name__ == "_property_not_important":
            return view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
        return None

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'utils.middleware.CheckPropertyMiddleware.ExcludePropertyMiddleware',
    # allow exclusion
    'utils.middleware.CheckPropertyMiddleware.CheckPropertyMiddleware',
]
```